# Play Framework Java Authentication for Assets

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, frameworks, assets

I have a Play application that creates files in the public folder when a user is in session. These files are like working files.

Now, with multiple users working at the same time, I want to restrict a user to his working files and not someone else's.

How do I achieve this ?

What I thought of :

- Have uuid based file name
- Store the files in the root of Application and send files to javascript using Java controller
- Authenticating before using any file

Comment: Your question is too broad. On SO you ask for specific issues with certain code/algorithm. It's not a place to ask others to write the code for you - especially big one!

Comment: @Qualcuno i'm not looking for code. I want to know the right technique

Comment: Stupid tag... choose better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some authentication framework(like [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/) or [Silhouette](http://silhouette.mohiva.com/)) and then manage files from controller. Once you are in `SecuredAction` or `UserAwareAction` you can get user identity and access the right file based on some propery of defined identity

Comment: Thank you .... What about storing a user's file in a directory named after the user's uuid(), as a consequence having a unique link ?

Comment: I dont know what is scale of your project, but you can do it as you say or use something like [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/).